# White tikz pictures in IguanaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, ghostscript, powerpoint

I'm trying to use [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) to include some TikZ pictures in a presentation, but I'm finding that if I'm drawing in white (or even a colour really close to white), the picture won't show.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{white}

hi

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->, thick, white] (3.5,0) -- (7.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

with the TIkZ picture ignored. If I don't include the "hi" or something like that, it errors:

[image]

But if I draw the line in a different colour, it'll come up properly, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{white}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->, thick, yellow] (3.5,0) -- (7.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

as expected.

It's probably some interaction I don't understand with the conversion process but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).